How to deserialize(without BinaryFormatter) data which has been serialized using BinaryFormatter
I have a data which has been serialized using BinaryFormatter. Now i want to deserialize the same data without using BinaryFormatter in c#

Why do you want to do this? BinaryFormatter is not removed, it's just obsoleted.

But it might be removed in future and because of security concerns didn't want to use BinaryFormatter

Take source code and modify as you wish.

Rewrite your serializer to use a new format and use the same format for deserialize of any new data. Then write a tool that uses the old and new serializer to create a migrator that moves all existing stuff to new format and then get rid of the old things.

I'm afraid, you can't satisfy all requirements simultaneously. In order to somehow read the existing data before further processing/conversion to the different format, you will need to use the BinaryFormatter logic in a whole or in part (as the original implementation or as a patched/custom one - it does not matter). And here you will hit the security problems, as such a problems are conceptual for a BinaryFormatter and not implementation-specific (except you have a very specific and simple object graph and you are ready to implement fully custom parser for this particular case) .
